# How to copy data from source workbook to current workbook through Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

I am trying to copy data from my source workbook by using FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).

but the code is always stuck at "sourceworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate", I assume it is BCS the selected file is too big so the Micro is not able to activate the correct sheet while it's still in the process of opening. hence I added a time to wait for the file completely open, which still failed.

here is what I got,

```
Sub Test()
Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
Dim currentworkbook As Workbook
Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set sourceworkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

        Starting_Time = Timer
        Application.Workbooks.Open.SelectedItems(1)
        Total_Time = Timer - Starting_Time
        Application.Wait (Total_Time)

        sourceworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
        sourceworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:CM60000").Copy
        currentworkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate

        Starting_Time = Timer
        currentworkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cell("A1").Paste
        Total_Time = Timer - Starting_Time
        Application.Wait (Total_Time)

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        sourceworkbook.Close
    End If
End With
Set sourceworkbook = Nothing
Set currentworkbook = Nothing
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("sheet1").Calculate
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: the error code : Run-time error '9'   subscript out of range

Comment: Does _sheet1_ in the workbook exist? Be aware _sourceworkbook_ is the active workbook when you start the macro and not the new opened workbook.

Comment: Agree with Shrotter, that error would suggest `Sheet1` doesn't exist. Also: You appear to be timing how long the paste takes, and then **once the paste has finished**, pausing for the same amount of time. I'm not sure that's doing what you're hoping. While it shouldn't really be necessary at all, if you're worried about timings when pasting lots of information, a `DoEvents` after the paste should ensure everything is done before execution continues.

Comment: @Shrotter i thought i "set" sourceworkbook "with" FileDialog which is the newly opened workbook i just selected?

Comment: @CLR I understand the error means the sheet does not exist, but it actually does exist in my workbook, that's why I assume it is BCS the file took too long to open and caused my script not able to locate the sheet1. that is also the reason I add a timer to wait for files completely opened.

Comment: @NickNick You can Try `Set sourceworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open.SelectedItems(1)` in your inner if clause

Comment: @Shrotter it says Syntax error and marked in red, i think it's not a correct script

Comment: `Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: comments in-line.  Note there should be no need to `Wait` - typically VBA does not continue until the (eg) open/paste operations are complete.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentworkbook As Workbook, Starting_Time, total_time
    
    Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    
            Starting_Time = Timer
            'Get a reference while opening the file
            Set sourceworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
            WaitSecs Timer - Starting_Time
            
            Starting_Time = Timer
            sourceworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:CM60000").Copy _
                currentworkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1")
            WaitSecs Timer - Starting_Time
            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            sourceworkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End With
    
    currentworkbook.Activate
    With currentworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Activate
        .Calculate
        .Range("A2").Select
    End With
End Sub

'wait for `secs` seconds
Sub WaitSecs(secs)
    Application.Wait Now + secs * (1 / 24 / 60 / 60)
    Debug.Print "waited " & secs & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: i got the error 438 for "sourceworkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:CM60000").Copy _
                currentworkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cell("A1"

Comment: the timer is not necessary, as long as I can copy the range of data from source to the current workbook through FileDialog, that's all I needed

Comment: My bad - `Cell("A1")` should have beeen `Range("A1")` - fixed above.

Comment: I changed script to below then it works

Set sourceworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
sourceworkbook.Worksheets("Prod Loc").ShowAllData
sourceworkbook.Worksheets("Prod Loc").Range("E4:CM60000").Copy

currentworkbook.Activate
currentworkbook.Worksheets("Raw").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues